# How to use stream to map the values of an object?

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have a class named `School`, and objects of this class have `Country` and `numStudents` instance variables. It doesn't really matter what they are beyond having those qualities, just assume they have a categorical and numerical variable that can be accessed with accessor methods (`getCountry(), getNumStudents()`).

The problem is that I want to map all `Country` to `numStudents`.

```
Stream<School> allSchools = {Yale, UCSD, Taipei, ...};
```

For example, if `Yale` and `UCSD` both have `USA` as their country, their students would be counted together. The map would look like this:

`{'USA' : 20000, 'Taiwan' : 10000, ...}`

I know how to use stream to make a frequency map if we are counting duplicates (i.e. map frequency of {A, A, O, B, B}), but I don't know how to change it around so that it will give me what I want for this application.

Comment: You can use the Collectors.groupingBy() collector along with the Collectors.summingInt() collector

Example:

      Map<String, Integer> countryToNumStudents = allSchools.collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(School::getCountry,
        Collectors.summingInt(School::getNumStudents)));

Comment: Could you set up some scaffolding code with sample classes and object lists? That'll save answerers some time.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Stream API to group the schools by country and sum the number of students for each country.

```
Map<String, Integer> countryToNumStudents = allSchools
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(School::getCountry, Collectors.summingInt(School::getNumStudents)))
```

If you don't want to use the sream API

```
Map<String, Integer> countryToNumStudents = new HashMap<>();
for (School school : allSchools) {
    String country = school.getCountry();
    int numStudents = school.getNumStudents();
    if (countryToNumStudents.containsKey(country)) {
        int currentNumStudents = countryToNumStudents.get(country);
        countryToNumStudents.put(country, currentNumStudents + numStudents);
    } else {
        countryToNumStudents.put(country, numStudents);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was thinking it would be solved with groupingBy, but I wasn't sure about which functions in the API would sum up the fields of the objects.

Comment: Your if/else can be replaced with `countryToNumStudents.merge(country, numStudents, Integer::sum);`.

Answer (score 1):

If  you don't want to use the stream, here is another way.

- Here [Map.compute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) will set the initial value if absent, or sum the next value to the existing one.

```
Map<String, Long> studentsPerCountry = new HashMap<>();
for(School school : schools) {
    studentsPerCountry.compute(school.getCountry(), (k,v)->v == null
            ? school.getNumStudents()
                    : v + school.getNumStudents());
}
```

And a simpler method than `Map.compute`, as pointed out in the comments by @VGR and @Holger is to use [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)).  Here is an example.

```
Map<String, Integer> studentsPerCountry = new HashMap<>();
for(School school : schools) {
    studentsPerCountry.merge(school.getCountry(),
                school.getNumStudents(),  Integer::sum);
}
```

Comment: Simpler with `merge`: `studentsPerCountry.merge(school.getCountry(), school.getNumStudents(), Integer::sum);`